# Change the MikTex Appdata folder for all users

Tags: miktex, installing

So. I have a Roaming profile on campus.  I want to have the \AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9 folder in a different place. I've already tried

--user-config=dir
--user-data=dir
--user-install=dir
and
--common-config=dir
--common-install=dir 
etc.. 
nothing seems to work. 
I use a local account for running the installation, then I use my networked student account to run lyx, that calls miktex. And whatever I do, it makes a mess in my roaming/Appdata folder

Anybody got any tips on how to change this ?

tl;dr: I want to change the AppData for MikTex to a different location, for all users.

P.S. I'm running windows 7, 64bit.

Comment: The MikTex Settings program  (found in the Maintenance or Maintenance (Admin) folders) can add new root directories.  Refresh FNDB will locate any sty files already there.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks, but I tried it now. And it is not working. when I view from lyx again it re-downloads the files instead of finding them in the new folder.